# Fourier transform in scipy and Parseval's identity

Tags: python, math, fft

While working on fft in Python, I'm running into problems with the normalization of the function and calculating the squared sum of the coefficients.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack 

# sample points
N = 1024

# sample spacing
T = 1.0/512.0

# example function
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = 1.5 * np.sin(5*2*np.pi*x) + 3 * np.sin(6*2*np.pi*x)

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': x, 'Y': y})

sumy = sum(abs(df['Y'])**2)

df['FFT (Y)'] = scipy.fftpack.fft(df['Y'])/(N/2)
df['FFT (freq)'] = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(N, T)

sumffty = sum(abs(df['FFT (Y)'])**2)

print sumy, sumffty
```

According to Parseval's identity, the sums should be equal; however, they're off by a factor of 256 (sumffty being the smaller one). What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

Parseval's theorem states that the total power in the two domains (space/time and frequency) are equal. Its statement, for DFT is [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/b/e/8/be83fa81d5079316074327a33c367ba1.png). Notice, that in spite of the 1/N on the right, this is not *mean* power, but *total* power. The reason for the 1/N is the normalization convention for the DFT.

Put in Python, this means that for a time/space signal `sig`, Parseval equivalence may be stated as:

`np.sum(np.abs(sig)**2) == np.sum(np.abs(np.fft.fft(sig))**2)/sig.size`

Below is a complete example, starting with some toy cases (one and two dimensional arrays filled one 1s). Note that I used the `.size` property of numpy.ndarray, which returns the total number of elements in the array. Hope this helps!

```
import numpy as np

# 1-d, 4 elements:
ones_1d = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.])
ones_1d_f = np.fft.fft(ones_1d)

# compute total power in space and frequency domains:
space_power_1d = np.sum(np.abs(ones_1d)**2)
freq_power_1d = np.sum(np.abs(ones_1d_f)**2)/ones_1d.size
print 'space_power_1d = %f'%space_power_1d
print 'freq_power_1d = %f'%freq_power_1d
```

I'm sorry I couldn't use your example directly--I'm not a Pandas user and couldn't understand it perfectly.

Comment: You're right, when I use the numpy.fft implementation, the returned sums are equal, but the scipy.fft implementation returns another answer. How can I get the scipy implementation to give me the 'right' answer?